# How to prevent Phpmailer sending embedded image as an attachment?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

I am sending an email with the logo of a company in it. However, it sending Base64 file as attachment on Gmail. The logo is inside the email and looks really good, but I do not understand why I see its code as an attachment.

This is my code:

```
$phpmailer->AddStringEmbeddedImage(base64_decode('...'), 'logo', 'logo', 'base64', 'png', 'inline');
.
.
.
<img style="max-width: 140px;" alt="" src="cid:logo">
```

What am I wrong with? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's because this is how embedded images work. The image *is* an attachment, it's just marked as inline, and has a content-id which can be used to target it from other elements in the MIME structure of the message. How this is displayed in email clients will vary. Some will display it only as referenced by the HTML, but others may show it as an attachment as well. But no matter what you do, the image will be part of the message. The only way for it not to be there is if you point at an external URL for the image, but then it's likely that the image will not be loaded at all.

The only other thing I can see you have wrong is that you have set the MIME type as `png`; it should be `image/png`. This might cause clients to mishandle the image. If you pass a filename with an extension, [the last 3 params](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringEmbeddedImage) can be left off as they will be set automatically or are the same as defaults, like this:

```
$phpmailer->AddStringEmbeddedImage(base64_decode('...'), 'logo', 'logo.png');
```

Comment: `$phpmailer->AddStringEmbeddedImage(base64_decode('...'), 'logo', 'logo.png', 'base64', 'image/png', 'inline');`
You are amazing, I did it  and it works!